# Focus on popup window's input field is not working in Edge browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, microsoft-edge

I am opening a child window through JavaScript. On the page load of a child window I want to set focus on input field.

Parent window's JS

```
window.open( url );
```

Child window's JS

```
$(function(){
document.getElementById("input-text").focus();
});
```

This is working in all browser except in EDGE.

Is there any solution for it?

Comment: Can you paste the html code of the child window please.

Comment: Can you make sure the jQuery part of your code is put at the end of the document. i.e. Just before the end of the body tag ?

Comment: @AkhilArjun The script is inside separate JS file